# Deserialize XML Node into a collection getting values from attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

if i have some xml like this

```
        <SiteSettings>              
            <sortOptions>
                <add name="By Date" value="date" />
                <add name="By Rating" value="rating" />
            </sortOptions>
        </SiteSettings>
```

I'd like to deserialise this into an object like this

```
[XmlRoot("SiteSettings")]
public class SerializableSiteSettings
{
    public List<NameValuePair> SortOptions { get; set; }
}

public class NameValuePair
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

I tried adding this to the SortOptions but it did not work

```
    [XmlArrayItem("actionButtons", typeof(List<NameValuePair>))]
    public List<NameValuePair> ActionButtons { get; set; }
```

Comment: public List<NameValuePair> SortOptions { get; set; } should be attributed with [XmlArray("sortOptions")] I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your use of [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

1. [`XmlSerializer` needs to know the types to expect when (de)serializing.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx#trblshtxsd_topic4)  When you have a field like `public object Value { get; set; }` it has no idea how to deserialize the field or what to expect therein.  You need to tell it that information -- but since `Value` is an [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) that suggests the field is something simple, like a string.  So, I'm going to assume in this answer that a string is sufficient to hold this information.
2. You need to tell `XmlSerializer` that your property named `SortOptions` is to be serialized with the name `sortOptions`, not `SortOptions`, using the [`XmlArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.
3. You need to tell `XmlSerializer` that `add` is the name of each array element, using the [`XmlArrayItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute.

Thus, the following works and reads `Value` into a string:

```
[XmlRoot("SiteSettings")]
public class SerializableSiteSettings
{
    [XmlArray("sortOptions")]
    [XmlArrayItem("add", typeof(NameValuePair))]
    public List<NameValuePair> SortOptions { get; set; }
}

public class NameValuePair
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

If `Value` is not a string and is really is some polymorphic type, you may need to implement `IXmlSerializable` for `NameValuePair`, along the lines of the following: [.NET XmlSerializer: polymorphic mapping based on attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774601/net-xmlserializer-polymorphic-mapping-based-on-attribute-value).

Comment: Thanks, those couple of issues got it working. I didn't realise i still had the value as an object.